Assertion Failed in Unreal Engine: MantleAsset.PositionCorrectionCurve in ALS Plugin
I'm encountering an assertion failure while working with the ALS (Advanced Locomotion System) plugin in Unreal Engine 5.1. The error occurs in the ALSMantleComponent.cpp file, specifically at line 96, when calling the MantleStart() function. Here is the error message:
Assertion failed: MantleAsset.PositionCorrectionCurve 
[File: D:\Work\first_in_the_city\Plugins\ALS-Community-4.24\Source\ALSV4_CPP\Private\Components\ALSMantleComponent.cpp] 
[Line: 96]

UnrealEditor_ALSV4_CPP!UALSMantleComponent::MantleStart() 
[D:\Work\first_in_the_city\Plugins\ALS-Community-4.24\Source\ALSV4_CPP\Private\Components\ALSMantleComponent.cpp:96]

UnrealEditor_ALSV4_CPP!UALSMantleComponent::MantleCheck() 
[D:\Work\first_in_the_city\Plugins\ALS-Community-4.24\Source\ALSV4_CPP\Private\Components\ALSMantleComponent.cpp:288]

UnrealEditor_ALSV4_CPP!UALSMantleComponent::OnOwnerJumpInput() 
[D:\Work\first_in_the_city\Plugins\ALS-Community-4.24\Source\ALSV4_CPP\Private\Components\ALSMantleComponent.cpp:412]```


The error seems related to the PositionCorrectionCurve of the Mantle asset, but I’m unsure how to resolve it. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
1. Verified the Mantle asset exists and is properly configured.
2. Checked the related curve asset for the Mantle, but I couldn't find any obvious issues.
3. Made sure my project is compatible with the ALS version (which was initially designed for Unreal Engine 4.24 but migrated to 5.1).

Has anyone encountered this issue or know how to fix it? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

